# Unable to start call using default phone or skype

Tags: reactjs, content-security-policy

I am unable to start call using default phone or skype in my react app. Following code is working locally but it is not working in production/live.

```
function onClick(event: any) {
    window.location.assign("tel:" + props.value);
}
```

here is the image that shows on local:

[image]

I am getting following error in production:

> Refused to frame '' because it violates the following Content Security
> Policy directive: "frame-src blob: data: https: mailto: ms-appx-web:
> ms-excel: ms-powerpoint: ms-visio: ms-word: onenote: pdf:
> local.teams.office.com:* localhost:* msteams: sip: sips:
> ms-whiteboard-preview:".

Please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my solution with the following code:

```
function onClick(event: any) {
    window.open("tel:" + props.value, '_system')
}
```